# Chartjs2 Stacked bar chart onclick and show information on which part i clicked in angular 7

Tags: angular, charts

i have questions about the stacked bar chart in chartjs 2. Which i want to get the information from the place that i clicked.
[image]

Like example i want to click on the first row, and click on the green colour one. How should i know the place that i clicked?
I want to know the information that i clicked, but i couldn't get the specific one. Only can get the information on the first row, which is "Persekutuan" with the total number that i have, but cant get the specific like :
"Persekutuan", "iphone X", "28"
What kind of the method that i able to retrieve those information?

I saw few example that only use in chartjs 1, is that other method i could use in chartjs2? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I search the internet and found one solution, here to share the information incase future use.

```
const chart = e.active[0]._chart;
const activePoints = chart.getElementAtEvent(e.event);
const datasetIndex = activePoints[0]._datasetIndex;

// if(activePoints.length > 0)
// {
const clickedElementIndex = activePoints[0]._index;
const label = chart.data.labels[clickedElementIndex];
const value = chart.data.datasets[0].data[clickedElementIndex];
console.log(clickedElementIndex, label, value, datasetIndex)
```

DatasetIndex is to get the position of the "iphone 8, iphone x, iphonexxx".